# Outlook splitting jpeg in half

Tags: html, email, outlook

Having to rebuild an email for a client and for some reason I am getting a strange glitch happening in Outlook (this is not happening in any other browser), where it is splitting the jpeg into 2. I have not seen this happen before and not sure how to fix it, anyone have any ideas?

[image]

```
    <td width="218" height="418" rowspan="5">
        <img alt="alt text here" border="0"
src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/m3img?l=9096912522165" style=
            "display: block; width: 218; height: 418;">
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, outlook does that because it uses very old rendering engine for HTML emails.
Instead of using width and height in your img tag, you should scale / fit the image using proper tr and tds along with aligning text on the left. If you had the whole html part, that could be of help.
https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-rendering-differences-in-microsoft-outlook-clients

```html
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <table>
         <tr>
           .....
           .....
           <td width="218" height="418" rowspan="5">
              <img alt="alt text here" border="0" src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/m3img?l=9096912522165" >
           </td>
           ....
           ....
        </tr>
       </table>
     </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Still getting the same results. Did try posting the rest of the code, though it says it is too long.